# django INCLUDE tag only takes one argument (can't use WITH)

Tags: django, google-app-engine

When I try to use the following include

```
{% include 'stream_doc.html' with doc=draft %}
```

in my HTML (`draft` is an object in the context of a loop iteration), I get the error:

```
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\lib\django_1_2\django\template\loader_tags.py", line 210, in do_include
raise TemplateSyntaxError("%r tag takes one argument: the name of the template to be included" % bits[0])
TemplateSyntaxError: u'include' tag takes one argument: the name of the template to be included
```

Can anyone tell me what's going on? So far as I can tell I'm following the Django [documentation](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/?from=olddocs#s-include). Is this something I can't do in app engine?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you miss the bit in the docs you linked to which says "Changed in Django 1.3"? Your path indicates you're running Django 1.2. You should be looking at [the 1.2 documentation](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/ref/templates/builtins/#s-include).

Comment: Totally missed that (I even looked around to see if there was a version reference, but still missed it). Thanks.

Answer (score 7):

On Django 1.2 and below, I believe it is possible to circumvent this with

```
{% with draft as doc %}
{% include "stream_doc.html" %}
{% endwith %}
```

At least it works for my use case where I was passing a fixed value as in the documentation using

```
{% with "Jane" as person %}
```

Comment: {% with "key" as "2" %}
{% include "article_edit/item.htm"  %}
{% endwith %} | this doesn't work...

Comment: I'm not sure about your context, but shouldn't it be `{% with "2" as key %}`? That is, assuming your key is known at the time of writing the template. Otherwise you may have to nest some `with` statements. See [Django | Built-in template tags and filters | Django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/ref/templates/builtins/#with) - actually that documentation seems to suggest that it's for caching a variable as a simpler name, and not for caching a value as a variable. Still, it worked for me when I tried `"Jane"` as the value of the `person` variable.

Comment: Fantastic. I just came back around to this problem in another context and found your solution here. Works great! Thanks!

Comment: In case you want to have two variables, use nesting of `with` statement `{% with "y" as autocomplete_box %} 
        {% with "y" as progress_bar %} 
        {% include "common_templates/page_header_bar.html" %} 
        {% endwith %} 
        {% endwith %} `